# Django admin: use one-to-one relationship in search_fields

Tags: django, django-admin, django-modeladmin

I am trying to to add a search to my model admin list page using the following Model and ModelAdmin classes:

**models.py**

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class UserProfile(models.Model):
        user = models.OneToOneField(User)
        country = CountryField(blank=True, null=True)
```

**admin.py**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from models import UserProfile

class UserProfileAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
        list_display = ('user','country')
        search_fields = ['user']
```

But I get the following error while trying to access the UserProfile  in admin panel:

```
 at /admin/profiles/userprofile/ Related Field has invalid
 lookup: icontains
```

I have also tried the following:

```
search_fields = ['user_username']
```

And

```
search_fields = ['user_name']
    def user_name(self,obj):
        return obj.user.username
```

Any solutions?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try using `user__username`, according to the [lookup API “follow” notation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.search_fields).